# Изменение цвета строки dqv с помощью checkbox и сохранение после перезапуска

Tags: c#

Изменяю цвет строки нажав на checkbox выделенную строку в dgv, но после перезапуска цвет строк не сохраняется. Читала о Properties.Settings, не получилось сохранить.

```
     private void checkBox1_CheckedChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
     if (dataGridView_zakaz.SelectedRows.Count != 0)
     {
         if (checkBox1.Checked == true)
         {
             foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView_zakaz.SelectedRows)                 
             {row.DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Orange; }
         }
         else
         {
             foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView_zakaz.SelectedRows)
             { row.DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.White;}
         }
     }
 }
```

[image: Все работает]

[image: Но после перезапуска, цвет строки не сохранился]

Comment: У вас должны быть данные отдельно, интерфейс (UI) отдельно, между ними должна быть связь. В текущем виде, сохранить это все будет тот еще гемор, ибо вы меняете напрямую UI какие-то значения. У вас должно быть условно `class User { public string Name {get;set;} public bool IsActive {get;set;} }` - это данные, заметьте, тут нет цвета или еще чего, тут есть примитивные значения. Ну а уже UI, в зависимости от того что у вас это такое (WPF/WinForms/...) должен привязаться (`Binding` к данным и на их основе задавать нужные цвета. Ну а имея на руках простой класс данных, сохранить его - 1 строка.